# zoo/xts - can't do math on 1-cell subsets? R hangs

Tags: r, xts, zoo

I'm using latest version of R/xts/zoo on Windows: R 2.15, xts 0.8-6, zoo 1.7-7

I'm seeing the following bizarre behavior, which was not the case with prior versions:

```
library(xts)
data(sample_matrix)
sample.xts <- as.xts(sample_matrix)

sample.xts[1, 2] - sample.xts[2,2]     # results in numeric(0)?!?!?!
(sample.xts[ 1, 2] - sample.xts[2,2])/sample.xts[3,1]  # if I run this twice R locks up
```

Here I have subset an XTS object to a single cell.  Subtraction no longer works.  Also, division causes R to completely lock up.

Does anyone else see this?  Is this a known bug or am I missing something?  I can reproduce this on two machines.

Session Info (a few packages deleted as confidential):

```
R version 2.15.0 (2012-03-30)
Platform: x86_64-pc-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats     graphics  utils     datasets  grDevices methods   base
```

Comment: BTW, I think this has something to do with the subset operation returning a zoo/xts object instead of a named numeric.  Perhaps this used to work for me because my environment(s) were setup such that the `[` was being hijacked by another package?  Anyways, doesn't explain the crash!

Comment: The output from `sessionInfo` may help determine why this worked for you in the past.  Also, a "hang" or "lock up" is not the same as a crash.  In a crash, the program terminates.  Regardless, the behavior is undesirable.

Comment: You are correct about crash v. hang.  I was being dramatic. =)  I updated title.  Thanks for the tip about sessionInfo()!

Comment: Wasn't as much of a 'tip' as it was a 'request for information'. :)

Comment: The hanging/crashing is fixed in xts on R-forge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never could subtract xts/zoo objects with non-overlapping indices.  Arithmetic operations always merge before performing the operation.  You need to use `coredata` in order for the subtraction you've written to provide the result you expect.

```
coredata(sample.xts[1,2]) - coredata(sample.xts[2,2])
```

I can replicate the second issue but I'm not sure this should be a high priority to fix, because it doesn't fit the zoo/xts idiom and would result in a completely empty xts object.  Everything is fine if (some of) the indices align.

```
(sample.xts[1,2] - sample.xts[1,3]) / sample.xts[1,4]
(sample.xts[2,2] - sample.xts[1:2,3]) / sample.xts[2:3,4]
```

Comment: I think this worked for me in the past because my package function was converting xts objects to named numerics via [.  I think this is the case because the function could not find [.zoo and fell-back on regular-old-matrix [.  So something about my environment must have changed such that my package function is now finding [.zoo.  does that make sense?

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich: Seems that an error _should_ be reported rather than causing a "hang" which would seem to require a restart and is basically be a "crash-equivalent".

Comment: @DWin: I know, I know.  But I'd really prefer to say, "then don't do that."