# Different result when multiplying xts objects vs. vector'ed xts objects

Tags: r, time-series, xts

I have the following original code

```
prices <- c(11.44, 12.64, 13.12, 11.98, 19.34)
dates <- seq(as.Date("2011-07-01"), by=1, len=length(prices))
ts.prices <- xts(prices, order.by =dates)

covariance <- function(x, convert.to.vec=FALSE) {
  if (convert.to.vec == TRUE)
    x <- as.vector(x)

  xbar <- mean(x)
  N <- length(x)
  i <- 1
  covariance <- sum((x[1:(N-i)]-xbar)*(x[(1+i):N]-xbar))

  return(covariance)
}
```

The output of the `covariance` function will be different whether `convert.to.vec` is `TRUE` or `FALSE`:

```
> covariance(ts.prices, TRUE)
[1] -5.679376
> covariance(ts.prices, FALSE)
[1] 4.445328
```

After adding some variables and `print`s to make debugging the code easier:

```
covariance <- function(x, convert.to.vec=FALSE) {
  if (convert.to.vec == TRUE)
    x <- as.vector(x)
  xbar <- mean(x)
  N <- length(x)
  i <- 1

  term.1 <- x[1:(N-i)]-xbar
  term.2 <- x[(1+i):N]-xbar
  term.3 <- term.1*term.2
  covariance <- sum(term.3)
  print(term.1)
  print(term.2)
  print(term.3)
  print(covariance)
  #covariance <- sum((x[1:(N-i)]-xbar)*(x[(1+i):N]-xbar))
  #return(covariance)
 }
```

We can see that the value of `term.3` is the one that is different:

```
> covariance(ts.prices, TRUE)
[1] -2.264 -1.064 -0.584 -1.724
[1] -1.064 -0.584 -1.724  5.636
[1]  2.408896  0.621376  1.006816 -9.716464
[1] -5.679376
> covariance(ts.prices, FALSE)
             [,1]
2011-07-01 -2.264
2011-07-02 -1.064
2011-07-03 -0.584
2011-07-04 -1.724
             [,1]
2011-07-02 -1.064
2011-07-03 -0.584
2011-07-04 -1.724
2011-07-05  5.636
                 e1
2011-07-02 1.132096
2011-07-03 0.341056
2011-07-04 2.972176
[1] 4.445328
```

When `convert.to.vec` is `TRUE`, `term.3` contains 4 floating numbers, whereas it contains 3 floating numbers when `convert.to.vec` is `FALSE`. So I'm assuming that the different value is caused by the multiplication of two xts objects vs. two vector'ed xts objects. Why is this the case ?

DC

Comment: I believe [Joshua's answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10516245/2414948) is relevant. `Ops.xts` seems to use `merge.xts` to account for overlapping "index"es before any arithmetic operation takes place.

Comment: @alexis_laz Thanks for the link. Can you post it as an answer so that I can accept it ?

Comment: I'm not fully aware of `xts` documentation, so not sure how to compose a formal answer. If the linked QA is sufficient, I guess, it could be marked as a duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @alexis_laz's comment, when an `Ops.xts` function such as `+` or `*` is used on two `xts` objects, both objects are first merged with each other if their indexes are not identical, as we can see in [xts`s sourcecode](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/xts/blob/81595e70b0e1632a511a91ca0dc6d885f8eb0469/R/Ops.xts.R#L35:L44):

```
if( NROW(e1)==NROW(e2) && identical(.index(e1),.index(e2)) ) {
  .Class <- "matrix"
  NextMethod(.Generic)
} else {
  tmp.e1 <- merge.xts(e1, e2, all=FALSE, retclass=FALSE, retside=c(TRUE,FALSE))
  e2 <- merge.xts(e2, e1, all=FALSE, retclass=FALSE, retside=c(TRUE,FALSE))
  e1 <- tmp.e1
  .Class <- "matrix"
  NextMethod(.Generic)
}
```

In my example, `term.1` and `term.2` have not identical indexes, thus both objects are merged, and the `Ops` function `*` returns an object containing overlapping dates only. One solution is to call `coredata` on the original `x` object.